# Change theme on material ui react template

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I purchased a material ui react theme (https://material-ui.com/store/previews/material-app/). It includes a number of themes such as dark, light, blue, indigo etc. By default it is set to "Dark" but can't figure out how to change it globally to "Light". I've searched online everywhere and played around but just cant figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/).

For example:

```
const darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: 'dark',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as it is paid will not able to solved it by sharing code.

In general, Template must contain default configuration value for theme (defaultTheme), to find it do following

as you shared link there is icon at bottom-left [image]
you can check in app code where is this located and on click how the theme is applied. You will find default configuration where you need to update `Light` instead of `Dark`